# Finding fastest cycle that gains at least x bonus points using backtracking algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path, backtracking

There's a map with points:

[image: Map with several nodes and a green and red number next to each]

The green number next to each point is that point's ID and the red number is the bonus for that point. I have to find fastest cycle that starts and ends at the point #1 and that gains at least x (15 in this case) bonus points. I can use cities several times; however, I will gain bonus points only once.
I have to do this with the backtracking algorithm, but I don't really know where to start. I've stutied about it, but I can't see the connection between this and a backtracking.

The output would look like this:

```
(1,3,5,2,1) (11.813 length)
```

[image: Same map as before with expected output route highlighted in orange]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Backtracking` is a technique applied to reduce the search space of a problem. So, you have a problem, you have a space with optimal and non-optimal solutions, and you have to pick up one optimal solution.

A simple strategy, in your problem, is to generate all the possible solutions. However, this solution would traverse the entire space of solutions, and, some times, being aware that *no optimal solution will be found*.

That's the main role of `backtracking`: you traverse the space of solutions and, when you reach a given point where you know no optimal answer will be achieved if the search continue on the same path, you can simply *repent* of the step taken, go back in the traversal, and select the step that comes right after the one you found to be helpless.

In your problem, since the nodes can be visited more than once, the idea is to maintain, for each vertex, a list of vertices sorted decreasingly by the distance from the vertex owner of the list.

Then, you can simply start in one of the vertices, and do the walk on the graph, vertex by vertex, always checking if the objective is still achievable, and backtracking in the solution whenever it's noticed that no solution will be possible from a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive backtracking algorithm to list all possible cycles and keep the best answer:

```
visitCycles(list<Int> cycleSoFar)
{
  if cycle formed by closing (cycleSoFar) > best answer so far
  {
    best answer so far = cycle formed by closing (cycleSoFar)
  }
  if (cannot improve (cycleSoFar))
  {
    return
  }
  for each point that makes sense
  {
    add point to cycleSoFar
    visitCycles(cycleSoFar)
    remove point from cycleSoFar
  }
}
```

To add a bit more detail:

1) A cycle is no good unless it has at least 15 bonus points. If it is any good, it is better than the best answer so far if it is shorter.

2) As you add more points to a cycle you only make it longer, not shorter. So if you have found a possible answer and cycleSoFar is already at least as long as that possible answer, then you cannot improve it and you might as well return.

3) Since you don't get any bonus points by reusing points already in the cycle, it doesn't make sense to try adding a point twice.

4) You may be able to speed up the program by iterating over "each point that makes sense" in a sensible order, for instance by choosing the closest point to the current point first. You might save time by pre-computing, for each point, a list of all the other points in ascending order of distance (or you might not - you might have to try different schemes by experiment).